# Generating a random number using a timer in capl

Tags: gcc, capl

I was trying to generate a random number in CAPL program (similar to C language) using timers.
Say I have a timer X and I start it

```
/****Timer start****/
on start
{ 
  settimer (x,20000);   // setting the timer for 20 secs
}
```

Now I need a random number only between 300ms to 20 secs with a resolution of 500ms.
CAPL has a inbuilt function called random() to do this.

I did like

```
int random(int x);
```

Now how can I make sure that I get a random value only with resolution of 500ms?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
y = random(40);
TestWaitForTimeout(300+y*500);
```

`y` gets a random value between 0 and 39, corresponding to 0-19.5 seconds with 500 ms resolution. Then you add 300ms to the total timeout. The resulting timeout will be between 300ms and 20s with a resolution of 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate random numbers by writing a test function as below.
The `random` function generates a `random` number between **0** to **n-1**.
As far as resolution is concerned the library function `random()` doesn't allow to vary the resolution.

```
testfunction Random_No ()

{

dword y;

y = random(20000);


TestWaitForTimeout(y);

}
```